# Visual Studio slowness, possible reason?

Tags: visual-studio

Im struggling with extremely slow Visual Studio. I use it to build C++ projects mostly.
Everything could be super slow. Menu's loading, intelIsense tips, builds. I've just tested building simple solution in 1 file, and build took around 5 minutes. But! I found this article about [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build-insights/tutorials/vcperf-and-wpa?view=msvc-170) which I used to trace this solution build. Despite overall time taking around 5 minutes, WPA report build took only around 0.686 seconds, attaching screenshot:

[image]

apparently I press "rebuild" in VS and build itself started ~300 seconds later(timeline).
Currently I use VS2019. Same problem I observed on VS2017. I did removed all VS components and installed VS2019 and problem is not gone. All other programs run fine. No excessive CPU load(intell 6700k), no noticeable harddrive usage(windows and VS components are on m2 ssd, lightning fast), 32 gb ram and enough free space on system disk.

Only VS extension I installed myself is QT extension for VS2019. Which actions can I take next to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

`devenv /safemode` from a command line starts the IDE in safe-mode with all plugins disabled.

Visual Studio Installer and repair install

Disable graphics acceleration in Visual Studio (Tools|Options|General ... there are a few "rich client visual experience" related things)

Check paths on your computer. If other apps run fine but one does not, it could be that this app tries to access a network drive or website which is not available.

Run "procmon" and "procexp" (Process Monitor/Process Explorer from Sysinternals) and take a look at what's going on.

Try VS 2022.